# deinit called in app but not in unit test when dismissing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, uikit

I'm trying to unit test the memory of my view controllers to see if they properly deinitialize when they're dismissed.

```swift
class SettingsViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var controller: SettingsViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController")
            as? SettingsViewController

        //load view hierarchy
        _ = controller.view
    }

    func testLogout() {
        let sideMenu = MockSideMenuViewController()
        var navController: UINavigationController? = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sideMenu)
        sideMenu.show(navController!, sender: nil)
        navController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        expect(navController).toNot(beNil())
        controller.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

        expect(navController).toEventually(beNil(), timeout: 3) // fails
        expect(self.controller).toEventually(beNil(), timeout: 3) // fails
    }
```

In the app, I use a segue to present my nav controller + SettingsViewController. It has a method that calls `dismiss` on itself, but when I check my controller instances, they still persist. In my view controller, I set a print statement to check if deinit is being called, and when I go through the steps on the app, it does get called (both controllers eventually go to `nil`). The unit test, however, doesn't do the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`controller` is a strongly-held property, so your test is retaining it.  Right now it only gets deinit'd on subsequent calls to `setUp()`.  If you want to test `controller.deinit` specifically, do `controller = nil` within your test.

You could probably do something like this:

```
var controller: SettingsViewController!  // <--- this is a strong ref

func testLogout() {
        let sideMenu = MockSideMenuViewController()

        // navController is a strong ref, held until the end of the scope; don't expect it to be nil
        var navController: UINavigationController? = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sideMenu)
        sideMenu.show(navController!, sender: nil)
        navController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

        // hold a weak ref to your controller and then nil out its reference
        weak var weakController = controller

        // remove the strong reference
        controller = nil

        // popping will release the last reference 
        navController?.popViewController(animated: false)

        expect(weakController).to(beNil(),) // succeeds
    }
```

Some notes:

- `navController` is a scope-level variable.  It won't be nil until the end of the function, so there's no reason to test or expect that.  It also certainly won't be nil right after you create it.
- [UIViewController.dismiss(...)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) is for dismissing modals. Your controller is part of a navigation stack.  dismissing won't do what you expect.

It feels like you're expecting `var navController: UINavigationController?` to be weak, but that's just not the case.  `weak` vars and properties should be `Optional`, but being Optional does not imply `weak`. See [Weak References](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).

Comment: Doesn't `dismiss` set the controller to nil? In the app instance, I don't have to manually set my view controller to `nil`. Where is my controller being referenced such that it's set to `nil` for me? Because in that code, I don't even have to call `weakController.dismiss` for the test case to pass.

Comment: Added some extra notes above.  dismiss does not set it to nil.  It dismisses a modal.  Also note that even if it set some reference to nil, you still have another reference not set to nil.  It doesn't affect other references you have to the same object.

Comment: I removed the call to dismiss.  Should have proofread my response a bit better before submitting haha. Hopefully the notes and edits clear it up a bit.

Comment: Also, what does this test achieve?  Do you think you have a retain cycle somewhere?

Comment: I have a separate router object that sometimes sets the `UIWindow` root to another controller, so I want to make sure the same views aren't presented on top of each other.

Comment: Note that neither the window nor the router are part of your test.  Your test basically doesn't test this.  At least, not as written.  It's also safe to assume that if it's not on the navigation stack, it won't be visible.

Comment: Also, I was trying to dismiss both the UINavigationController and its child because they are presented as modals. Would that still work? Calling dismiss, even on the navigation, still doesn't set my weak reference to nil.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192338/discussion-between-huy-anh-hoang-and-kid-x).